# How to change background color of button in flutter when selected?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

the image of an issue is as following

[image]

Comment: you can create a condition when `onPressed` event executed

Comment: can you explain it a bit more pls

Comment: i using this code but its only hapening when pressed on it i want change the color when taped like selected and when i click on one button background color  to black and other to white and vice versa             if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                                  return Colors.green;
                                } else {
                                  return Colors.black;
                                }

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I shared the code  in the answer please review the code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a stateful widget. Make one boolean value isSelected (False as default) and whenever the button is pressed setState the isSelected to true. Now go back to the button color and use the ternary operator.

```
isSelected? (New Color) : (Default Color)
```

Here is my sample code.

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2, vertical: 2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: foodtype == 'Veg' ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.circle,
          color:
              foodtype == 'Veg' ? Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 177, 36) : Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```